# Multithreading, return value on Control.Invoke()

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, winforms, delegates

I'm using multithreading on a win application with

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate{}, null);
```

The problem is my method needs a return value on the main thread (a DialogeResult object) and with `this.Invoke()` I can't get the value from main thread. Here's the method code:

```
public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, PSSettings.Settings settings, string title, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons)
    {

        return (DialogResult)((Form)owner).Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            PSMessageBox mb = new PSMessageBox();
            mb._settings = settings;

            mb.lblTitle.Text = title;
            mb.lblCaption.Text = caption;
            mb.Buttons = buttons;

            return mb.ShowDialog();
            mb.ShowDialog(owner);
        }));
    }
```

Can anyone show me how to get the return value from the invoke method with a delegate of any kind?

Comment: Normally a `QueueUserWorkItem` should not be opening a modal form. You should use the ThreadPool for short background work and are you sure you can cast a `IWin32Window` to a `Form`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, PSSettings.Settings settings, string title, string caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons)
{
    DialogResult result;

    ((Form)owner).Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        PSMessageBox mb = new PSMessageBox();
        mb._settings = settings;

        mb.lblTitle.Text = title;
        mb.lblCaption.Text = caption;
        mb.Buttons = buttons;

        result = mb.ShowDialog(owner);
    }));

    return result;
}
```

But remember, while your dialog is openend, your thread is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The `Action<*>` delegates do not return anything.
You need the generic `Func<*>` delegates, which do.

Answer (score 0):

```
        DialogResult res;
        ((Form)owner).Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            PSMessageBox mb = new PSMessageBox();
            mb._settings = settings;

            mb.lblTitle.Text = title;
            mb.lblCaption.Text = caption;
            mb.Buttons = buttons;


            res = mb.ShowDialog(owner);
        }));
        //user res
```